# Landscape Orientation on iPad using Sencha Touch 2

Tags: ios, ipad, extjs, ios9, sencha-touch-2

I develop iPad app using Sencha Touch 2.4. My ipad using iOS 9. The problem is when I turn my iPad landscape and I open my app, the display of my app is a mess. like this

[image]

btw my screen app is the blue one.

But when I turn my iPad portrait then I open my app it's normal and when I turn my iPad landscape my app also turn landscape normally. Just when I open my app in landscape mode will be unnormal.

Please any body can help me?

Thanks,
Seno

Comment: Are you developing a hybrid app using phonegap/cordova, if yes, which version of cordova do you use? Or are you inside the browser?

Comment: ya, I am developing a hybrid app, I using adobe phonegap builder to generate my app. I think my cordova is version 2.0

Comment: Cordova 2.0 is outdated. Google Play store does not accept any less than Cordova 4.1.2 (I think - or was it 4.1.1?) for security reasons. You should definitely update. Perhaps this will also solve your problems, because outdated versions of cordova are not able to cope well with new versions of mobile OSes and browsers.

Comment: owh okay thank you, i'll try to update my cordova.

Comment: owh,, i'm sorrry,, btw i'm using cordova 3.9 for iOS and cordova 4.1.1 for android. but it's still problem with the landscape display.

Comment: have u set orientation to all in config.XML?

Comment: no, the orientation in config.xml I set "default"

Answer (score 0):

i am also getting same issue. when i open landscape mode in iphone and ipad.

In config.xml file i set "default" only

Comment: You build with Adobe Phonegap Build also?